# A question regarding #if defined (macro name)

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#if !defined(_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#endif
```

So the above is the first 4 lines of C language code from a file of some project.

I do know that #if defined (macro name) means that if the macro is defined, the value of the expression is 1 and if not, then it's 0.

So basically, the first two lines will be either 1 or 0 but what would they do? 1 or 0 just sitting alone?

Answer (score 3):

It's `defined()` which will be evaluated to either `0` or `1` and from that value `if` will decide if it should go to the body. It's like normal `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically, the first two lines will be either 1 or 0 but what would they do? 1 or 0 just sitting alone?

No, the `#if` would stay, just the `defined()` would become `0` or `1`.

So assuming for example `_WIN32` and `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` were defined, then the 1st two line you show looked like:

```
#if 1
#if 0
```

---

Those two if-statements control if what is following is taken into account until the *next* `#endif` statement.

The above snippet though is incomplete and should look like this:

```
#if 1
#if 0
#define FOO 42
#endif
#endif
```

The above would not `#define` `FOO`.

The below would not `#define` `FOO` as well:

```
#if 0
#if 1
#define FOO 42
#endif
#endif
```

The following *will* define `FOO`:

```
#if 1
#if 1
#define FOO 42
#endif
#endif
```

---

Back to your example code:

The stuff "controlled" by the outer if-statement

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
```

is

```
#if !defined(_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

The stuff "controlled" by the inner if-statement

```
#if !defined(_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
```

is

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Comment: that's my point. there's if, but there's no body for that if statement. if 0, do {this and that } but there's no this and that. do you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: thank you for the explanation. It clarified everything. the reason why I was so  confused was because 'normal if statements' have this form: if (condition) {do something}. so I guess the if statement as preprocessor directives don't use parentheses(that surround the conditional statement) nor braces(that surround the body).

Comment: @NewLearner: "*preprocessor directives don't use parentheses*" Well is does, just in an unusual manner: The line starting with `#if ...` opens the scope  and the line holding `#endif` closes it.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically, the first two lines will be either 1 or 0 but what would they do? 1 or 0 just sitting alone?

```
#if expression
```

won't result in a line replaced by the result of `expression` but the preprocessor will decide upon the value of `expressen` in

```
#if expression

controlled text

#endif /* expression */
```

if it will process the `controlled text` or not.

Comment: what do you mean by controlled text?

Comment: the lines beween `#if ...` and `#endif`.